# c# MVC and Webform pass variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

My application is an MVC application but I need to use the Report Viewer control which is only a Webform control.

Current I use a cookie to pass parameters from my MVC application to the aspx page but I am wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Have you checked out this project? https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started

Comment: I can't recall. It's been a long few weeks. I know I did try something from codeplex but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

We are also forced to use the Report Viewer control for various reasons in our MVC application right back to ASP.NET MVC <= 2 way back when. We simply put in an ignore for it in the routes and run the folder it is in like a micro Web Forms app.

In the code behind for the actual ReportViewer Web Form, we look for specific parameters and send them from Session overlaid functions and helpers:

```
foreach (ItemParameter rp in parameters)
{
  if (rp.Name == "ReportUser")
    paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportUser", CurrentUser.Id.ToString(), false));
  if (rp.Name == "Current_User_Id")
    paramList.Add(new ReportParameter("Pas_Current_User_Id", CurrentUser.Id.ToString(), false));
```

...and so on and so forth, with that parameter list being supplied to us by the SSRS Web Service' GetItemParameters method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getitemparameters.aspx

P.S. I'm not advocating this as best practice, by the way. It was simply what we had to do to make things work in the early days of MVC. I like the look of the Codeplex project mentioned in the OP comments. That looks far more elegant to me.